# Azure: Orchestration file transfers - Which Azure components are best suited?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, file-transfer

I have a project in which we need to transfer files (mostly SFTP-based, but also HTTP), between 20+ systems. We have currently identified +200 different files that needs to be transferred. We would like a setup in Azure where the different transfers can be setup, monitored and logged, however, we are unsure which way to go.

**The question is:** Which Azure components would be best suited for the above task? Which components would you use?

One possible solution would be to implement at large set of Azure functions, each responsible for one file transfer. This would require us to setup the monitoring ourselves, and it will result in a very large number of functions.

We have also been looking towards Azure data factory and Azure Logic apps, but we are unsure if they would provide any benefits with regards to monitoring, re-running failed jobs etc.

Comment: Data Factory should be the best fit for this. Especially regarding monitoring, re-running etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned in your description,obviously, Azure Function is not suitable for your scenario because you have to build a large number of functions to do the transfer work.Moreover,it's painful to monitoring such scale of function executions.You need to distinguish the log data and persist them into table storage or something like that which causes more cost. So,it's passed!

In my opinion, ADF is the best solution for you.It could be monitored by [many ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor) and it supports re-run feature,please follow  this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Rerun-activities-inside-your-Azure-Data-Factory-pipelines).Also,another distinct feature for ADF is Self-Hosted Integration Runtime which supports transmission between on-premise system and Azure cloud environment.

As for Logic App,i'm can't find any re-run feature related to it so i don't think it could attract your attention.